# NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readFor(..)

Tags: jackson, fasterxml

I'm using the following fasterxml dependencies and still facing following error :

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readerFor(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader;

```
    ObjectMapper instance = new ObjectMapper();
    instance.readerFor(UserM.class);

Dependencies:
     <jackson.version>2.8.8</jackson.version>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>           
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: `ObjectMapper#readerFor` was introduced in Jackson v 2.6 (https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readerFor(java.lang.Class)). Your runtime classpath probably contains an older version somewhere.

Comment: Is this error from Maven or from your IDE? Run a Maven dependency-tree from command to find out what version you actually ended up in your classpath.

Comment: After cleaning and building the local repository It worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ObjectMapper readFor method is introduced with 2.6 version.
Your runtime probably using an older version of library. If you are using eclipse you can check what version you are using under the referenced libraries.

[image]